# Need help in aggregate function in R

Tags: r

```
 MaxVal=aggregate(test$a,by=list(Date=test$OF_DATE),FUN=max
```

OF_Date is a column with daily dates of five years, hence when I use above function I get the maximum value of 'a' from all the dates , but I need maximum value of 'a' every month.

```
  Date            a
2008-01-15       25
2008-01-29       10
2008-01-30       30
2008-02-02       15
2008-02-09       45
2008-03-05       60
2008-03-29       55
```

Si when I run this function my output is

```
2008-03-05       60
```

but I need my output to be

```
2008-01-30       30
2008-02-09       45
2008-03-05       60
```

How can I do this . Separating the dates , i.e months and comparing ?

Comment: You could use month as the `by` variable in the `aggregate` call. For example, `aggregate(cbind(a, Date) ~ format(Date, "%m") , data = test, max)[-1]`. Although you need to then put `Date` in date format again. BUT why is the date in your output always the fifth?

Comment: Sorry that was an typing error !

Comment: @user20650 Can I use it in a 'by' if I want to aggregate by multiple conditions ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Yes, you can use `by` (for example, `with(test, aggregate(cbind(a, Date) , list(date=format(Date, "%m"), othervariable) , max))`, where othervariable may be several other variables). You can also do this in the formula format (as before) with `aggregate(cbind(a, Date) ~ format(Date, "%m") + othervariable , data = test, max)` .  If you are still unsure please edit your question with a wee example. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `format` to reduce the date to years and months. A call to aggregate is printed below.

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
  "Date            a
  2008-01-15       25
  2008-01-29       10
  2008-01-30       30
  2008-02-02       15
  2008-02-09       45
  2008-03-05       60
  2008-03-29       55")

dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)
dat$Month <- format(dat$Date, "%Y-%m")

aggregate(a ~ Month, data=dat, max)
```